# HTML Table with Rowspan and Colspan

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

[image: My jsp view]

I want to show data from my server to view as like the above image.In java, How can i arrange data structure in my server to view like this? Is there any particular data structure in java to do like this?

Comment: *What have you tried?* Plus, this question does not seem to be about data structures (and this is by no means "complex"), but about drawing tables?

Comment: to show like this...i have to structure the data and make the response from server as an object..and iterate that object in my view..In this case rowspans and colspans are used, so i can't iterate it simply

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.crionics.com/public/swing_examples/JTableExamples4.html) and do a few "JTable multi rowspan" searches on SO

Comment: @MadProgrammer  solved it myself

Answer (score 1):

```
Object [][] structure = new Object [5][];
structure [0] = new Object [] {c1_d1, c1_d1, c1_d1, c1_d1}; // col1
structure [1] = new Object [] {c2_d1, c2_d2, c2_d2, c2_d2}; // col2
structure [2] = new Object [] {c3_d1, c3_d2, c3_d2, c3_d3}; // col3
structure [3] = new Object [] {c4_d1, c4_d2, c4_d3, c4_d4}; // col4
structure [4] = new Object [] {c5_d1, c5_d2, c5_d3, c5_d4}; // col5
```

Each column is represents by an array and merged cells represents by range of array elements storing reference to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Table` datastructure from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html)

Comment: How would it help implementing rowspans?

Comment: rowspan is usefull only if you want to display the table, otherwise it is just cell with same value, it is not clear what raj want here.

Comment: if each columns in html table have same span, i can simply iterate the object from server in view..but here my columns in table is not equally spanned